# Is my hardware what's causing Eevee not to render?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, hardware, memory-management

I've been using Blender 2.79 for a few weeks and just upgraded to 2.8. I want to try out a bunch of new tutorials using Eevee but it looks like I might not have a powerful enough computer. I've been looking at the requirements and such but I'm not really good at this sort of thing.

I can render a scene with Quick Smoke added at 1920x1024 in Eevee (the quality renders *ok*... it only took 36 seconds but the image just pops up and there's no count down letting me know how long it was supposed to take.) If I try to render the scene any larger Blender just gets hung up and nothing happens. Is this because I need to fill up those 2 empty memory slots I have?

I also saw the requirements said Eevee requires GPU capabilities. My Mac doesn't have that and I'm not sure exactly how (or if) I can upgrade my computer to that.

Thanks for any help!

[image]

Comment: Definitely not that two slots issue, 32 GB RAM is quite enough for 3D usage. The problem might be your GPU - Radeon 575, it only got 4 GB memory, which might not be able to render large scene in EEVEE. You should provide more information on why you think it is not rending and what did you rendered

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I don't have any other info yet. I'll keep working at it.